Как сделать автоматическую проверку статуса платежа в ЮКасса?
Сейчас я использую проверку платежа при нажатии кнопки "Проверить платёж", но пользователь может забыть её нажать. Мне нужно автоматически проверять оплатил пользователь товар или нет.
Всем заранее спасибо!

Таск создай, пусть в фоне дергается
